# Docker sync files

Tags: docker, symfony

im not familiar with docker at all. im trying to use symfony with docker (windows). for docker i use (without changes, only +mysql)
https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker
it works well
problem that when i change files or create new files changes not sync, only after new build.
Please tell how to write proper dockerfile so files from host (and from docker) will be in sync
i need to use docker volumes, but idk how

dockerfile
ARG PHP_VERSION=8.1
ARG CADDY_VERSION=2

```
# "php" stage
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-alpine AS symfony_php

# persistent / runtime deps
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        acl \
        fcgi \
        file \
        gettext \
        git \
    ;

ARG APCU_VERSION=5.1.21
RUN set -eux; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        $PHPIZE_DEPS \
        icu-data-full \
        icu-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        zlib-dev \
    ; \
    \
    docker-php-ext-configure zip; \
    docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
        intl \
        zip \
    ; \
    pecl install \
        apcu-${APCU_VERSION} \
    ; \
    pecl clear-cache; \
    docker-php-ext-enable \
        apcu \
        opcache \
    ; \
    \
    runDeps="$( \
        scanelf --needed --nobanner --format '%n#p' --recursive /usr/local/lib/php/extensions \
            | tr ',' '\n' \
            | sort -u \
            | awk 'system("[ -e /usr/local/lib/" $1 " ]") == 0 { next } { print "so:" $1 }' \
    )"; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .phpexts-rundeps $runDeps; \
    \
    apk del .build-deps

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql

COPY docker/php/docker-healthcheck.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-healthcheck
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-healthcheck

HEALTHCHECK --interval=10s --timeout=3s --retries=3 CMD ["docker-healthcheck"]

RUN ln -s $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini
COPY docker/php/conf.d/symfony.prod.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/symfony.ini

COPY docker/php/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf

COPY docker/php/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint

VOLUME /var/run/php

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-allow-superuser
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.composer/vendor/bin"

WORKDIR /srv/app

# Allow to choose skeleton
ARG SKELETON="symfony/skeleton"
ENV SKELETON ${SKELETON}

# Allow to use development versions of Symfony
ARG STABILITY="stable"
ENV STABILITY ${STABILITY}

# Allow to select skeleton version
ARG SYMFONY_VERSION=""
ENV SYMFONY_VERSION ${SYMFONY_VERSION}

# Download the Symfony skeleton and leverage Docker cache layers
#RUN composer create-project "${SKELETON} ${SYMFONY_VERSION}" . --stability=$STABILITY --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-progress --no-interaction; \
#   composer clear-cache

###> recipes ###
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
#RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .pgsql-deps postgresql-dev; \
#   docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) pdo_pgsql; \
#   apk add --no-cache --virtual .pgsql-rundeps so:libpq.so.5; \
#   apk del .pgsql-deps
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
###< recipes ###

COPY . .

RUN set -eux; \
    mkdir -p var/cache var/log; \
    composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-progress --no-scripts --no-interaction; \
    composer dump-autoload --classmap-authoritative --no-dev; \
    composer symfony:dump-env prod; \
    composer run-script --no-dev post-install-cmd; \
    chmod +x bin/console; sync
VOLUME /srv/app/var

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint"]
CMD ["php-fpm"]

FROM caddy:${CADDY_VERSION}-builder-alpine AS symfony_caddy_builder

RUN xcaddy build \
    --with github.com/dunglas/mercure \
    --with github.com/dunglas/mercure/caddy \
    --with github.com/dunglas/vulcain \
    --with github.com/dunglas/vulcain/caddy

FROM caddy:${CADDY_VERSION} AS symfony_caddy

WORKDIR /srv/app

COPY --from=dunglas/mercure:v0.11 /srv/public /srv/mercure-assets/
COPY --from=symfony_caddy_builder /usr/bin/caddy /usr/bin/caddy
COPY --from=symfony_php /srv/app/public public/
COPY docker/caddy/Caddyfile /etc/caddy/Caddyfile
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    # NOTE: use of "mysql_native_password" is not recommended: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password
    # (this is just an example, not intended to be a production configuration)
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      target: symfony_php
      args:
        SYMFONY_VERSION: ${SYMFONY_VERSION:-}
        SKELETON: ${SKELETON:-symfony/skeleton}
        STABILITY: ${STABILITY:-stable}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
    environment:
      MERCURE_URL: ${CADDY_MERCURE_URL:-http://caddy/.well-known/mercure}
      MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL: https://${SERVER_NAME:-localhost}/.well-known/mercure
      MERCURE_JWT_SECRET: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeMe!}

  caddy:
    build:
      context: .
      target: symfony_caddy
    depends_on:
      - php
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: ${SERVER_NAME:-localhost, caddy:80}
      MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeMe!}
      MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeMe!}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config
    ports:
      # HTTP
      - target: 80
        published: ${HTTP_PORT:-80}
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTPS
      - target: 443
        published: ${HTTPS_PORT:-443}
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTP/3
      - target: 443
        published: ${HTTP3_PORT:-443}
        protocol: udp

volumes:
  php_socket:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you declare on the dockerfile level, the dockerfile is a layer you tell the container (or the host) to add the container in it's run time. (Installations, copies..)

this a flag on the docker API `docker run -v vol:vol .... ```

Or inside of the docker-compose file

I see your docker-compose file has a declaration of volumes for service caddy.

Try to init the volume as an empty one

```
# bottom of the docker-compose file

volumes: 
   php_socket: {}
```

Docker is built upon layers, every change you'll make, will create a new layer and will be saved on the volume.